# Using environment variables in Tmux status bar shell commands

Tags: environment-variables, tmux, date

I am attempting to create a tmux status bar which shows three timezones:
`US Eastern Time :: UTC :: Central European Time`. Using the `TZ` environment variable makes the `date` command show the time in a given timezone.

I was attempting to do so with this tmux.conf setting:

`set -g status-right "#[fg=white]#S #I:#P #[fg=yellow]:: %d %b %Y #[fg=green]:: #(TZ=America/New_York date +%H:%M) :: #(date -u +%H:%M) UTC :: #(TZ=Europe/Belgrade date +%H:%M)"`

However, passing `TZ=foo` does not work inside of `#(…)`. (I get the server `date` instead of what I expected). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tmux expands time formats with [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) in `status-left` and `status-right` before it expands `#(…)` and other sharp escape sequences. So `%H:%M` is expanded to the local time first, and `date` runs with an argument that is already numeric.

Double the percent signs.

```
set -g status-right "#[fg=white]#S #I:#P #[fg=yellow]:: %d %b %Y #[fg=green]:: #(TZ=America/New_York date +%%H:%%M) :: #(TZ=UTC date -u +%%H:%%M) UTC :: #(TZ=Europe/Belgrade date +%%H:%%M)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with tmux but I guess the problem is that `#()` does not work the same way like `$()` in the shell.

The problem may be solved by forcing the use of a shell:

```
#(bash -c 'TZ=Europe/Belgrade date +%H:%M')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work (in tmux 1.6, Gentoo). It's still printing the UTC date.

Comment: @Excalibur Quite strange. Try creating a wrapperscript (with `TZ=Europe/Belgrade date +%H:%M`) and `#(/path/to/wrapperscript)`

Comment: Yeah, that solution did occur to me. Although since this tmux.conf is set dynamically using Chef, I'm hesitant to add any external dependencies. Perhaps I should file an issue with tmux. Thanks though!